# how to make a header position fixed while scrolling down

Tags: java, android, scrollview

Within a `NestedScrollView` how do you make every Header stay at a specific point while scrolling down in this case right under the Image until another Header comes by while scrolling down which pushes the first Header and gets replaced by the 2nd Header and so on. I hope the image makes sense to what I am trying to accomplish. Thank You!

[image]

Comment: Do you want to achieve something like this : [Sticky list headers gif](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders/master/demo.gif), the page : [StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders)

Comment: Please check the following page https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve this you should not use NestedScrollView instead use a linear layout with Image at the top then a listview with sticky header. I think this will solve your problem

Here is the link for the list you want. https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders